# Postman API update collections

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

I am using Postman to test the Rest service with swagger 2.0 specs. I want to update the existing collection with multiple test cases with the new API specs.
Can anyone suggest a solution that will keep all existing requests and update the collection?

Comment: I tried using Postman API update collections service. However it removes all existing test cases

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep that collection and update that with some test cases then you can duplicate that collection and update that duplicated one. It will let you have a backup of that previous collection and work on that same collection as well.

Comment: I tried this one but it keeps removing the existing test cases

Comment: did you save them properly before duplicating?

Comment: Yes. Postman support told me the issue is with my API file. Will update if the problem is resolved. Thanks.

Comment: you're most welcome